# PHP 7.3 doesn't show in WPI in IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8, iis-8.5

I have 3 Windows servers, two of them are Windows Server 2012 R2 - IIS 8.5 and the other is Windows Server 2012 - IIS 8.0

I wanted to update to PHP 7.3.x automatically through the Web Platform Installer, but in both R2 boxes with IIS 8.5 there appears no version of PHP 7.3.x in WPI, While on the IIS 8.0 box, PHP 7.3.7 appears on WPI.

Does anyone why doesn't PHP 7.3.x appears in the IIS 8.5 WPI ? If so will it at some point? Must I do something ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My impression of [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is that [WebPI is slowly being phased out](https://forums.iis.net/post/2143268.aspx).